# Cannot find Console.Writeline in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, monogame, console.writeline

I'm using c# in visual studio 2017. I've written a Console.Writeline() somewhere within my application but I can't remember where I've written it. I'm wondering if there's a tool in visual studio that can help me find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files` and searching for `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: `Ctrl+F` will open the find dialog. You can put the cursor in your `Update` method and choose "Current Block" for the search, then either click the right-arrow button to walk through the results, or choose "Find All" if you want to see all of the calls in a separate window below (which is pretty handy). If it's happening in some method that's called by your Update method, then you would need to expand your search to "current document", "current project", or "entire solution"

Comment: Have you got it now?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it with `ctrl + shift + f` and select `entire solution` option and then search it.

In bottom windows you will get `find result` tab in that you will get your result .